# Construct function not working in Laravel helper

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel version 6.x. I have created one helper function called **GraphqlApi**.

My helper class will look like below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

/**
 * GraphqlApi class
 */
class GraphqlApi
{
     public function __construct() {
          echo "test";die;
     }
}
```

But whenever I call any function from helper class **construct** function is not being called.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: can you show how you called other functions?, Btw `Helpers` is namespace not a class. `GraphqlApi` is the class

Comment: Im telling **GraphqlApi** is a helper.. And im calling it : `GraphqlApi::getGuzzleRequest()`

Comment: And im getting result properly

Comment: `getGuzzleRequest()` this is a static method. so the class is not being initialized, so the constructor is no being called.

Comment: Can u tell me wat is the solution please..

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: I want to use construct function in **GraphqlApi** (helper class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you always want the constructor to be called when you are calling other methods.

First, you can not have `static` method.

Second, call the method this way.

```php
$graphqlApi = new GraphqlApi();

$result = $graphqlApi->getGuzzleRequest();
```

This way the constructor will be called.